# Health conditions over medical consultations

Tags: timeline

this is my ugly and unstyled UI but wich is enough for demo :p

[image]

it's for a healthcare application, so basically the doctor check/uncheck health conditions from the available predefined list and the datagrid update accordingly.

this small screen is just for an examination form to collect symptoms .
i have other screens for other informations .

the predefined list came from the doctor i am working with , and these symptoms are related to his speciality (cardiologist)
in this way the doctor can add one or more symptoms "quickly"
then he can use the second column of the datagrid to add more details if he like

this work fine for the first consultation, But what if it's the 3rd, 4th or even more visit

i want to show the various health conditions over differents consultations 
so the doctor can view and also quickly confirm or not the states based on the last consultation

hopefully i am explaining correctly

any idea is welcome .

.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand impressions:

1. Be sure the list of associated symptoms or illnesses are correct before you demo. Professionals will trust you more if you show that you have taken the time to learn about their specialty.
2. Repeating and highlighting the list items on the left in the first column of the drop-down or popup menu on the right is an unfamiliar pattern that many might find confusing. At any rate, it seems unnecessary. It's probably better to highlight the parent category (e.g. *fatigabilité*) on the list item on the left and show the selected state of the child condition (oppression thoracique) on click on the right.
3. If your idea is to create a medical app which shows the patient's current diagnosis and symptoms in a form the doctor can edit, you may have the wrong design pattern here (testing on doctors will tell you if that's so). This looks like a form you fill out once and submit. An editable medical record would show at a glance, vitals such as the patient's name, age and sex, the "[presenting problem](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/presenting+problem)", [Co-Morbidities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comorbidity) etc. in a scannable format such as the popular and mobile-friendly card layout.

Comment: thanks for taking time to resopnd , please look at my edited question .